# How do the JavaScript relational comparison operators coerce types?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

What rules apply for the JavaScript relational comparison operators when the operands are of different types?

For example, how is `true > null` evaluated? I can type this into my developer console and it gives the result `true`, but why?

I searched for a bit, but didn't find any blog posts explaining this, although there are plenty explaining type coercion for == and === comparison operators.

Comment: Dear downvoters, please note that StackOverflow [explicitly encourages asking and answering your own questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), so I would appreciate some feedback explaining why my question is receiving downvotes while my answer is receiving upvotes :-)

Comment: Your answer is quite good. Your question... not so much. Remember, self-answered questions are indeed encouraged but getting the question part right is *hard*. If your question is not of outstanding quality and is not marked community wiki, it may well be downvoted or even closed. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163623/what-can-i-do-to-improve-the-question-portion-of-a-self-answered-android-debuggi for examples of what you can do to curb this.

Comment: im not gonna downvote, YET, i want to see your answer to this: how you make such question and less than 1 min later you give a detailed and complete answer? You really had the doubt?

Comment: I'm not one of the downvoters, but I believe the question is too generic. It's a little better after the edit, and can now be read as a request for an explanation of the `null > true` case. That's more Stack Overflow-ish.

Comment: @Ark, that doesn't really matter, you can post questions that you already know the answer to. The quality of the question, however, is paramount here.

Comment: @Ark there's actually a specific option when you ask a question to answer it straight away as well

Answer (score 24, accepted):

JavaScript relational comparison operator type coercion is defined in the [JavaScript specification](http://es5.github.com/), specifically in sections [11.8 to 11.8.5](http://es5.github.com/#x11.8) which describe the operators, and sections [9.1 (ToPrimitive)](http://es5.github.com/#x9.1) and [9.3 (ToNumber)](http://es5.github.com/#x9.3) which describe the process of coercing the operands.

In short, the 4 comparison operators (`<`, `>`, `<=`, and `>=`) do their best to convert each operand to a number, then compare the numbers. The exception is when both operands are strings, in which case they are compared alphabetically.

Specifically,

1. If an argument `o` is an object instead of a primitive, [try to convert it to a primitive value](http://es5.github.com/#x8.12.8) by calling `o.valueOf()` or - if `o.valueOf` wasn't defined or didn't return a primitive type when called - by calling `o.toString()`
2. If both arguments are Strings, compare them according to their [lexicographical ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). For example, this means `"a" < "b"` and `"a" < "aa"` both return true.
3. Otherwise, [convert each primitive to a number](http://es5.github.com/#x9.3), which means:

   - `undefined` -> `NaN`
   - `Null` -> +0
   - `Boolean` primitive type -> `1` if `true`, `+0` if `false`
   - `String` -> [try to parse a number](http://es5.github.com/#x9.3.1) from the string
4. Then compare each item as you'd expect for the operator, with the caveat that any comparison involving `NaN` evaluates to `false`.

So, this means the following:

```
console.log(true > null);           //prints true
console.log(true > false);          //prints true
console.log("1000.0" > 999);        //prints true
console.log("  1000\t\n" < 1001);   //prints true

var oVal1 = { valueOf: function() { return 1; } };
var oVal0 = { toString: function() { return "0"; } };

console.log(oVal1 > null);         //prints true
console.log(oVal0 < true);         //prints true
console.log(oVal0 < oVal1);        //prints true
```