# JS If Condition of Undefined

Tags: javascript

I have a user database like this:

```
const user = {
  subscription: {
    plan: 'free_trial',
  },
};
```

I need to check some condition before user changes plan.

```
const currentDate = new Date();
if (user.subscription.trialExpDate > currentDate) {
  // do something
} else {
  // trialExpDate is either undefined or <= currentDate
  user.subscription.trialExpDate = currentDate;
}
```

My question is, for some users `trialExpDate` will be `undefined`. Is it okay to compare `undefined` against `currentDate` object? Or do I need to check if `trialExpDate` exist first?

Comment: What is `user.subscription.trialExpDate` ? Is it a string ? Try `new Date(user.subscription.trialExpDate)`

Comment: `user.subscription.trialExpDate` is either `undefined` OR a `date` object

Comment: `undefined > new Date();` will always be `false`.. I would have tested the value before comparing..

Comment: yeah that was my question. so you would test if it's undefined first before doing the rest of the code? even if it returns same answer and shorter code?

Comment: I certainly would have tested it.. That would make my code more readable..

Comment: Can `user.subscription.trialExpDate` be a `null`?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest check with `hasownproperty`.
Sample:

```
if (user.subscription.hasOwnProperty('trialExpDate') && user.subscription.trialExpDate > currentDate) {
  // do something
} else {
  // trialExpDate is either undefined or <= currentDate
  user.subscription.trialExpDate = currentDate;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll do that instead :)

Comment: `trialExpDate` is not `ownProperty` of `user` object, it belongs to `user.subscription`

Comment: What if `user.subscription.trialExpDate` is `null` ? It will return `hasOwnProperty` `true`.. I will go with `if(user.subscription.trialExpDate && .....)`

Comment: Yes, @Rayon that is one scenario. If we are confident that won't be null we can use hasownproperty otherwise your we have to check as you said

Answer (score 1):

You can just check if it is `null`.

```
if (user.subscription.trialExpDate != null || user.subscription.trialExpDate > currentDate) {
    // do something
}
else {
    // do something else
}
```

The `variable != null` will simultaneously check if the variable is null or undefined.

Comment: You can read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647867/how-to-determine-if-variable-is-undefined-or-null

Comment: What if `user.subscription.trialExpDate` is `0` ? I would have had a function to test if it is a valid `Date`..

Comment: Then he could check as well if it is indeed `0`.

Answer (score 0):

In short: **if you're sure that `user.subscription.trialExpDate` cannot be a `null`**, using your original code is **very okay**.

See [how the JavaScript relational comparison operators coerce types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14687877/4510033).

**If `user.subscription` always exist and it is always an object**, comparison between a `Date` object, and an `undefined` or a `NaN`, is evaluated as `false`. However, for a `null`, it is evaluated as `+0`, thus `null < (new Date)` will be `true`, `null > (new Date)` will be `false`.

When JavaScript **relational** comparison works,

1. A `Date` object is converted to *its timestamp*, which is `(The Date object).valueOf()`.
2. A primitive is converted to a `number`, which means:

   - an `undefined` is converted to a `NaN`;
   - a `null` is converted to `+0`.
3. Then the comparison is performed between each item as you'd expect for the operator. Note that any comparison involving a `NaN` evaluates to false.