# How do I specify this range using a regular expression in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers, range

I need to check if the first 6 digits of a number are from 222100-272099. 
This is in JavaScript, and I'm not sure how to go about implementing it. 
My initial thought was something like: 
match(/^2[2-7][0-9]$/), but I'm not sure how to specify this range correctly.

Comment: (/^2[2-7][0-9]{4}$/) might be what you are looking for?  {number} is how many of the previous character you want.  If that does the trick I'll write up an answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read first in the help center, how to ask a good question on this forum: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. So we can better unterstand your question and can help you with your problems.

Comment: [Now you have two problems](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

Comment: @sniperd Your regex would also match 279000, which is not in the range.. but that's just not a job for regexs.

Comment: Oh, right! Ha.  I should probably read the whole question :)

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn’t really use a RegEx for that. It is better to substring the string and then compare:

```
const n = Number.parseInt(str.substr(0, 6), 10);
if (222100 <= n && n <= 272099) {
   // ...
```

Comment: Be careful with this. It will also match `22210a` or `25ujid`. You may want to run it through `parseInt()` too.

Comment: Really? `const str = '22210a'; const n = str.substr(0, 6); 222100 <= n && n <= 272099` returns false for me.

Comment: That's a much more ideal solution. It worked perfectly - Thanks!

Comment: No, you're right. The comparison operators [coerce both sides to `Number` if they are not both `String`s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14687877/2347483).

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are for pattern matching in strings:
[Wikipedia: Regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

You can use JavaScript's parseInt() function to turn your 6 numeric character string into a number that can be used to do a simple greater than/less than check.
[W3C: parseInt()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)