# How to use a value of an input text in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input

I'm building a functionality on my "pig game", so the user can set himself the winning value if he wish, by entering it in an input field.

I need to use the value the user enter in an `<input type="text">`, in order to change a behavior in my JavaScript code.

I wrote my input as :

```html
<div class ="newInputScore">
    <label for="fixGoal">SET THE GOAL :</label><br>
    <input name = "fixGoal" type = "text" id = "fixGoal">
</div>
```

and I need to use the value the user write in the above input, in my JS code. So far, I tried :

```js
let choosenScore = parseInt(document.getElementById('fixGoal').value);
if (scores[activePlayer] >= 100 || scores[activePlayer] >= choosenScore){...
```

... but it seems like my input is returning me a value of 0, because the player is actually winning with a score > 0 with the above code. I console log()'ed choosenScore and it returns me NaN, then undefined on the line below. What am I missing there? Thanks in advance.

link to the project (dices don't appears because files are on my computer) : https://codepen.io/Peyo5202/pen/dybqyXV

Comment: *"it seems like my input is returning me a value of 0"* . Did you log it to see if the value is really 0?

Comment: Check if the value is really 0 with a console log and parse choosenScore to an integer, now it is a string.
Check also the value of scores[activePlayer] with a console log

Comment: I console loged "choosenScore" and it now returns me NaN, and undefined on the line below. I actually added parseInt() to choosenScore, though im not sure i whrote it well. Any other advice?

Comment: What gets logged when you remove `parseInt`?

Comment: Please include a [mre]. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so.

Comment: [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/sv-SE/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) on an empty string gives you [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) (Not a Number)

Comment: When i console.log "choosenScore" without parseInt, it returns me undefined. I also provided a link to a codepen with the project (dices arent shown because files are on my computer).

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more details, as you can see, your code works...

```js
let choosenScore = parseInt(document.getElementById('fixGoal').value);
```

```html
<div class ="newInputScore">
    <label for="fixGoal">SET THE GOAL :</label><br>
    <input name = "fixGoal" type = "text" id = "fixGoal">
</div>

<button onclick="console.log(parseInt(document.getElementById('fixGoal').value))">Start</button>
```

Comment: Code doesnt worck because as soon as you hold any value, you win the game.Even if you stated say like "50" in the input, if you hold any number you instatnly win the game. I think it has to do with this part : ```if (scores[activePlayer] >= 100 || scores[activePlayer] >= choosenScore)```. It seems to set choosenScore to "0", no matter what you whrite in the input.

Answer (score 0):

There is type coercion (attempt to convert variables to same type) when you try to compare two variables that are not of the same type with javascript comparison operators - in your case, `undefined` converts to `NaN` and

> ...with the caveat that any comparison involving `NaN` evaluates to `false`

see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687876/how-do-the-javascript-relational-comparison-operators-coerce-types/14687877#14687877) to get a full explanation of this. Finally, `false` converts to `+0`.

**Suggestion:**

Why not just put a default value of `"0"` for the input

```html
<div class ="newInputScore">
    <label for="fixGoal">SET THE GOAL :</label><br>
    <input name = "fixGoal" type = "text" id = "fixGoal" value = "0">
</div>

<button onclick="console.log(parseInt(document.getElementById('fixGoal').value))">Start</button>
```

or better still, get the value of `choosenScore` with a ternary operator

```js
function choosenScore() {
    let choosenScore = document.getElementById('fixGoal').value;
    return parseInt(choosenScore ? choosenScore : 0);
}
```

```html
<div class ="newInputScore">
    <label for="fixGoal">SET THE GOAL :</label><br>
    <input name = "fixGoal" type = "text" id = "fixGoal">
</div>

<button onclick="console.log(choosenScore())">Start</button>
```