# Logical Operations Dilema

Tags: javascript, operators, logical-operators

I was trying to add some form validation to a simple form I was working on earlier and I wrote the following snippet

```
      if (!lesson.title && lesson.title.trim().length == 0) throw Error("Kindly provide a lesson title");
```

Then it occurred to me to try something unconventional, instead of the logic "length **EQUALS** zero", I wanted to try "length **NOT EQUAL TO OR LESS THAN** zero", then I came up with the following snippet

```
      if (!lesson.title && lesson.title.trim().length <=! 0) throw Error("Kindly provide a lesson title");
```

To my surprise, I worked, but I didn't really understand the logic behind that so I tried out a couple of assertions with the outcomes:

```
"s".length <=! 0 // TRUE
"sm".length <=! 0 // FALSE

"s".length =! 0 || "s".length < 0 // TRUE
"s".length =! 0 && "s".length < 0 // FALSE
"sm".length =! 0 && "sm".length < 0 // FALSE
"sm".length =! 0 || "sm".length < 0 // TRUE
```

Can someone kindly explain to me what is going on here? I'm confused.

Answer (score 3):

`<=!` is not an operator. It is two operators:

- [Less than or equal `<=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Less_than_or_equal)
- [logical NOT `!`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT)

Therefore, the expression

```
"s".length <=! 0
```

can be re-written more clearly as:

```
"s".length <= !0
```

which reads as "the length of the string **s** should be less than or equal to NOT zero".

---

The value `0` is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), therefore inverting it with a NOT produces boolean `true`

```js
console.log( !0 )
```

Now we can re-write the expression to the equivalent:

```
"s".length <= true
```

---

Next thing comes in with [how relational operators compare different types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687876/how-do-the-javascript-relational-comparison-operators-coerce-types). In short, if you compare a number and a boolean, then the boolean will be coerced to a number. The value `true` coerces to `1`

```js
console.log( Number(true) )
```

Therefore, the final re-write of the expression is:

```
"s".length <= 1
```

---

In the end, `<=! 0` is a very roundabout way of getting the wrong comparison.

---

> instead of the logic "length EQUALS zero", I wanted to try "length NOT EQUAL TO OR LESS THAN zero", then I came up with the following snippet

There is no "not equal to or greater" as we saw. The opposite operators for relationships are:

- `==` <-> `!=`
- `===` <-> `!==`
- `>` <-> `<=`
- `>=` <-> `<`

If you want "not equal to or less than" the exact opposite is "greater than":

```js
console.log( "5 <= 4", 5 <= 4 );
console.log( "5 > 4 ", 5 > 4 );

console.log( "5 <= 5", 5 <= 5 );
console.log( "5 > 5 ", 5 > 5 );

console.log( "5 <= 6", 5 <= 6 );
console.log( "5 > 6 ", 5 > 6 );
```

The other option is to negate the whole comparison which will give identical results:

```js
console.log( "5 <= 4",   5 <= 4 );
console.log( "5 > 4 ", !(5 <= 4) );

console.log( "5 <= 5",   5 <= 5 );
console.log( "5 > 5 ", !(5 <= 5) );

console.log( "5 <= 6",   5 <= 6 );
console.log( "5 > 6 ", !(5 <= 6) );
```